# Build a binary decision tree for all number combinations equal to a value

Tags: tree, binary-tree

I need help understanding this homework assignment. I need to build a binary decision tree that finds all possible "shifts for a job". Basically, you enter a job S and an array of numbers that represent length of shifts. The task is to find all possible combinations of the shifts that equal S.

example:

```
list of shifts: 43 12 54 3 8 18 3 2 9 15
S = 23
some possible combinations: 12, 3, 8 and 18, 3, 2
```

I am confused on how to implement this. He mentioned "a traversal to a left child means selecting a job to a shift where as a traversal to a right child means not selecting given job to a shift"

I don't need the code necessarily, although obviously it would be helpful :) 
p.s. He seemed to make a point to not use a binary search tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the shifts are arriving in the given order, since they are in a list.

Let's say we're at the first position of the list. Let's make a node, this will also serve as the root of the tree. This node is current node. The first number 43 is put into the current node. Now, we can either chose to take it or not. Since 43 is bigger than 23, we don't take it. That means we go down the left branch from the node containing 43. Now tree is:

```
43
```

Then we get 12. So our tree would look like this (sidewise arrow means right child or shift taken, downward means left child or not taken). :

```
43
|
12
```

If we take it, then we have to go down the right branch. The next number is 54, let's put that in the current node :

```
43
|
12 - 54
```

We cannot take 54, its too big. So we go down the left branch. Next number is 3, put that in the current node :

```
43
|
12 - 54
      |
      3
```

This number 3 is taken. So is the next number 8. That gives us 23. Let's put a sentinel value, the x symbol here. This will denote that we've reached 23. The tree looks like this now :

```
43
|
12 - 54
      |
      3 - 8 - x
```

Now, we trace back to 8. What if we didn't take it ? Then we would go down the left branch to find 18. The tree would look like :

```
43
|
12 - 54
      |
      3 - 8 - x
          |
          18
```

We wouldn't take 18 because it's too big. Then next comes 3, 2 .. we keep building the tree in this manner :

```
43
|
12 - 54
      |
      3 - 8 - x
          |
          18
           |
           3 - 2 - 9
                   |
                   15
                   |
                   o
```

We put another sentinel value o at the left child of 15 to indicate that we cannot go any farther because the input has exhausted. We can trace back now up to 2, then consider not taking 2, then receive 9 again from the list. But that also cannot lead us to a sum of 23 :

```
43
|
12 - 54
      |
      3 - 8 - x
          |
          18
           |
           3 - 2 - 9
               |   |
               9   15
               |   |
               15   o
               |
               o
```

And it goes on :

```
43
|
12 - 54
      |
      3 - 8 - x
          |
          18
           |
           3 --- 2 - 9
           |     |   |
           2-9   9   15
                 |   |
                 15  o
                 |
                 o
```

Anywyas, ultimately we'll have a tree where some of the leaf nodes will contain x indicating success. The number which you took right turn at on the path to that node gives you the sum 23.